# MySQL Query with 3 AND

Tags: php

I'm trying to get from database many fields to check user account.

On form, user fill in code, pass and email.

I need to check if user code exist, if password is correct, if email is correct and user have level 1 or 2 to go ahead.

I'm trying with query below, but i'm redirected to error page.

Where do I wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (`user_code` = '". $user_code ."')
                              AND (`user_pass` = '". $user_pass ."')
                              AND (`user_email` = '". $user_email ."')
                              AND ((`user_level` = '1') OR (`user_level` = '2'))
                              LIMIT 1";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
        header("Location: index.php?message=error"); exit;
```

Comment: Check the field names.

Comment: How are the `$user_code`, `$user_pass`, and `$user_email` variables set?  Are you getting them from `$_POST` or `$_GET`?

Comment: Yes, I get with POST: $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];

Comment: `echo $sql;` whats the output?

Comment: Found error Dragon. Strange, but Database table was corrupt. ('') Thanks all helped.

Comment: You are asking for SQL injection. Read about mysqli and proper quoting/escaping/sanitizing input for DB queries.